# Removing single quotes from kendo spread sheet

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are using Kendo Spreadsheet control to provide excel like features for the end users. We have set of rows for which values will be pasted from the MS excel sheet. Based upon these cell values,  the below row cells will have its own calculation.

But while pasting, the cell values are appending with single quotes as shown in screenshot which is causing error in its dependent cell.
How can I avoid appending single quotes with values on the kendo spread sheet cells when I am copying the data's from msexcel sheet ?

[You can see value in the red box is appended with single quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLt3E.png)